# factory is undefined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a factory in AngularJS based on [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/08/16/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service.aspx). But I am getting an error saying "dataFactory" is undefined in my controller. My code looks like this:

```
MyApp.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http)
    {
        var urlBase='/someurl/roles/';
        var dataFactory={};

        dataFactory.getRoles=function()
        {
            return $http.get(urlBase+'getlist');
        };

        dataFactory.addRole=function(roleName, roleCss)
        {
            return $http.get(urlBase+'add&name='+roleName+'&css='+roleCss);
        };

        dataFactory.updateRole=function(role)
        {
          return $http.get(urlBase+edit&id='+role.id+'&name='+role.name+'&css='+role.css');
        };

        dataFactory.deleteRole=function(role)
        {
            return $http.get(urlBase+'remove&id='+role.id);
        };

        return dataFactory;
    }]);

MyApp.controller('RoleCtrl',['$scope','$http','dataFactory', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,dataFactory) {
     dataFactory.getRoles().then(function(res){
        $scope.roles = res.data.result;   
      });
 }]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're missing the string version of '$rootScope'

So instead of

```
MyApp.controller('RoleCtrl',['$scope','$http','dataFactory', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,dataFactory) {
```

use (note the addition of `'$rootScope'`):

```
MyApp.controller('RoleCtrl',['$scope','$http','$rootScope','dataFactory', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,dataFactory) {
```

`dataFactory` was going into $rootscope since you had a misalignment of parameters. And then there was nothing to send in to `dataFactory`.  Thus your error.

Comment: You saved my day. Sometimes my mouse just deletes random bits of code and I wouldn't even notice it. Cheers mate!